# Is it possible to create "Insensitive Table and Column name" in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I am working on PostgreSQL 9.2 and i want to create a table with capital letter without using double quotes.Is it possible by any how? means

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(NAME VARCHAR(50));
```

i want the table name must be look like "STUDENT" But postgresql automatically convert it into "student". So is there any way exist to disable sensitive property of postgresql for column and table names?
thank you.

Comment: No, this behavior is not configurable. State the problem you're trying to solve (why you would need that) for better answers.

Comment: Hi Deniel, Thanks for replying quickly

Comment: Actually i am working on a project in which the same code is used by Sql Server,Oracle and PostgreSQL. sql server support for both either lower or upper but the problem is, Oracle stores everything after converting into uppercase and postgresql does the viceversa. so i am getting the problem when i am using select query with like operator e.g. select * from database_name where table_name like 'LDH_%' this query return all the table names starting with LDH_ because oracle stores everything in upper case so it works for oracle but not for postgresql

Comment: You could use driver-specific views for that, or simply re-write your query to use something like `... WHERE UPPER(table_name) LIKE 'LDH_%'`. While `information_schema` is in the SQL standard, drivers implement it differently. (In this specific case, postgresql is the one, which does not conforms to the standard: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html - right above "Constants")

Comment: thank you pozs, Could you please explain that how can i use driver-specific views and second option could be a good choice if i will not get any solution. Is there any configuration setting exists at the time of database installation so that i can configure and disable sensitive nature for column and table name.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? The JDBC driver can return the information whether the database stores the names in upper,lower or mixed case

Comment: i'm using java language.