# How to change postgresql to store table names in uppercase without changing the way of accessing it

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, uppercase

i am working on postgresql 9.2 and i am getting more difficulties with storing the table name in postgres in lower case. Is there any way so that we can store tables in upper case and retrieve using upper case or lower case instead of using double quotes in postgresql. thank you in advance.

Comment: No, not possible. And you already got that answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217205 As a general rule: Never, ever use quotes for column or table names. Thus you don't have to care whether they are upper or lowercase.

Comment: ok sir here i got my answer, thanks